# Не реагирует на нажатия телеграмм бот

Tags: python, telebot

Я написал бота на телебот и сделал инлайн клавиатуры, я новичок в телеботе и до конца не понял как работает call_back, у меня есть меню: Смотреть новости/Настройки. При нажатии на любую все отлично, если я перехожу в настройки, то там еще одна клавиатура, но при нажатии на нее ничего не происходит.

```
import telebot
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='токен')
language_var='ru'
category_var=''
country_var=''
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main_menu(message):
    markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Смотреть новости',callback_data='CheckNews'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton('Настройки', callback_data='Settings'),
               )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='*Меню:*', reply_markup=markup,parse_mode="Markdown")
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def news_settings_handler(call):
    if call.data=='Settings':
        settings_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        settings_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Язык', callback_data='Language_settings'),
                   types.InlineKeyboardButton('Категория', callback_data='Category_settings'),
                            types.InlineKeyboardButton('Страна', callback_data='Country_settings'),
                   )
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*Настройки:*', reply_markup=settings_markup, parse_mode="Markdown")

        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
        def settings_handler(call):
            if call.data == 'Language_settings':
                language_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                language_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский', callback_data='ru'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Английский', callback_data='en'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Немецкий', callback_data='de'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='back')
                                    )
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*На каком языке вы хотите читать новости?*',
                                 reply_markup=language_markup,parse_mode="Markdown")
                @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
                def language_handler(call):
                    global language_var
                    if call.data=='ru':
                        language_var='ru'
                    elif call.data=='en':
                        language_var='en'
                    elif call.data=='de':
                        language_var='de'
                    elif call.data=='back':
                        main_menu(call.message)
            elif call.data == 'Category_settings':
                category_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                category_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Спорт', callback_data='sport'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Бизнес', callback_data='business'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Развлечения', callback_data='entertainment'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Общее', callback_data='general'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Медицина', callback_data='health'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Наука', callback_data='science'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Технологии', callback_data='technology'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Все категории', callback_data='Default'),
                                    )
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*Какие новости вы хотите читать?*',
                                 reply_markup=category_markup, parse_mode="Markdown")

                @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
                def category_handler(call):
                    global category_var
                    if call.data == 'sport':
                        category_var = 'sports'
                    if call.data == 'business':
                        category_var = 'business'
                    if call.data == 'entertainment':
                        category_var = 'entertainment'
                    if call.data == 'general':
                        category_var = 'general'
                    if call.data == 'health':
                        category_var = 'health'
                    if call.data == 'science':
                        category_var = 'science'
                    if call.data == 'technology':
                        category_var = 'technology'
                    if call.data == 'Default':
                        category_var = ''
            elif call.data == 'Country_settings':
                country_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                country_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Китай', callback_data='ch'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('США', callback_data='us'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Россия', callback_data='ru'),
                                    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Польша', callback_data='pl'),
                                   types.InlineKeyboardButton('Украина', callback_data='ua'),
                                   types.InlineKeyboardButton('Германия', callback_data='de')
                                    )
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*Новости из какой страны вы хотите читать?*',
                                 reply_markup=country_markup, parse_mode="Markdown")

                @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
                def country_handler(call):
                    global country_var
                    if call.data == 'ru':
                        country_var = 'ru'
                    elif call.data == 'us':
                        country_var = 'us'
                    elif call.data == 'de':
                        country_var = 'de'
                    elif call.data == 'ua':
                        country_var = 'ua'
                    elif call.data == 'ch':
                        country_var = 'ch'
                    elif call.data == 'pl':
                        country_var = 'pl'
    elif call.data=='CheckNews':
        global category_var
        global language_var
        global country_var
        titles = []
        descriptions = []
        if category_var!='' and country_var!='':
            top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(category=category_var,language=language_var,country=country_var)
            for article in top_headlines['articles']:
                titles.append(article['title'])
                descriptions.append(article['description'])

        elif category_var!='' and country_var=='':
            top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(category=category_var, language=language_var)
            for article in top_headlines['articles']:
                titles.append(article['title'])
                descriptions.append(article['description'])

        elif category_var=='' and country_var!='':
            top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(language=language_var,country=country_var)
            for article in top_headlines['articles']:
                titles.append(article['title'])
                descriptions.append(article['description'])

        elif category_var=='' and country_var=='':
            top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(language=language_var)
            for article in top_headlines['articles']:
                titles.append(article['title'])
                descriptions.append(article['description'])

        for i in range (len(titles)):
            try:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*'+titles[i]+'*\n'+'\n'+descriptions[i],parse_mode="Markdown")
            except:
                pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделал всё что было...

```
# делаем словарь с юзерами
users = {}


# делаем функцию для более удобного получения данных из словаря
def get_data(user_id: int, data: str, default=None):
    users.setdefault(user_id, {"state": "", "language_var": "ru"})
    return users[user_id].get(data, default)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message: types.Message):
    # при старте делаем запись юзера в словарь
    users.setdefault(message.from_user.id, {"state": "", "language_var": "ru"})

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Смотреть новости', callback_data='CheckNews'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton('Настройки', callback_data='Settings'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='*Меню:*', reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="Markdown")


# как вы можете заметить я разбил всё что вы написали на отдельные хендлеры,
# старайтесь ридерживаться именно такого написания кода
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "Settings")
def news_settings(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    settings_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    settings_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Язык', callback_data='Language_settings'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Категория', callback_data='Category_settings'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Страна', callback_data='Country_settings'))
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='*Настройки:*', reply_markup=settings_markup, parse_mode="Markdown")


# ловить нужный колбек можно вот так
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "CheckNews")
def check_news(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # пользуемся нашим словарем, если данных в нем не будет, то вернет пустую строку
    category_var = get_data(call.message.from_user.id, "category_var", '')
    language_var = get_data(call.message.from_user.id, "language_var", '')
    country_var = get_data(call.message.from_user.id, "country_var", '')

    titles = []
    descriptions = []
    if category_var != '' and country_var != '':
        top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(category=category_var, language=language_var, country=country_var)
        for article in top_headlines['articles']:
            titles.append(article['title'])
            descriptions.append(article['description'])

    elif category_var != '' and country_var == '':
        top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(category=category_var, language=language_var)
        for article in top_headlines['articles']:
            titles.append(article['title'])
            descriptions.append(article['description'])

    elif category_var == '' and country_var != '':
        top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(language=language_var, country=country_var)
        for article in top_headlines['articles']:
            titles.append(article['title'])
            descriptions.append(article['description'])

    elif category_var == '' and country_var == '':
        top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(language=language_var)
        for article in top_headlines['articles']:
            titles.append(article['title'])
            descriptions.append(article['description'])

    for i in range(len(titles)):
        try:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             text=f'*{titles[i]}*\n{descriptions[i]}',
                             parse_mode="Markdown")
        except Exception:
            pass


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "Language_settings")
def lang_settings(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    language_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

    # я поменял колбек дату, для того чтобы понимать откуда именно был колбек
    # в этом случае я добавил префикс choise_lang чтобы бот реагировал на их всех, но не на другие
    language_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский', callback_data='choise_lang:ru'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Английский', callback_data='choise_lang:en'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Немецкий', callback_data='choise_lang:de'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='choise_lang:back'))
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                     text='*На каком языке вы хотите читать новости?*',
                     reply_markup=language_markup,
                     parse_mode="Markdown")


# такие колбеки ловим вот так
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("choise_lang"))
def language_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # к слову колбек дата ведь уже другая и её нужно обработать, мы разбиваем стоку по : и берем правую часть
    result = call.data.split(":")[1]
    # сразу обработаем вариант с кнопкой назад
    if result == "back":
        main_menu(call.message)
        return
    # если же это была нажата не кнопка назад, то тогда просто запишите колбек в дату, не вижу смысла в куче ифов
    users[call.message.from_user.id]['language_var'] = result


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "Category_settings")
def category_choise(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    category_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    category_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Спорт', callback_data='choise_category:sport'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Бизнес', callback_data='choise_category:business'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Развлечения', callback_data='choise_category:entertainment'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Общее', callback_data='choise_category:general'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Медицина', callback_data='choise_category:health'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Наука', callback_data='choise_category:science'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Технологии', callback_data='choise_category:technology'),
                        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Все категории', callback_data='choise_category:Default'))
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                     text='*Какие новости вы хотите читать?*',
                     reply_markup=category_markup,
                     parse_mode="Markdown")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("choise_category"))
def category_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    result = call.data.split(":")[1]
    if result == "Default":
        users[call.message.from_user.id]['category_var'] = ''
        return

    users[call.message.from_user.id]['category_var'] = result


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "Country_settings")
def category_choise(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    country_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    country_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Китай', callback_data='choise_lang:ch'),
                       types.InlineKeyboardButton('США', callback_data='choise_lang:us'),
                       types.InlineKeyboardButton('Россия', callback_data='choise_lang:ru'),
                       types.InlineKeyboardButton('Польша', callback_data='choise_lang:pl'),
                       types.InlineKeyboardButton('Украина', callback_data='choise_lang:ua'),
                       types.InlineKeyboardButton('Германия', callback_data='choise_lang:de'))
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                     text='*Новости из какой страны вы хотите читать?*',
                     reply_markup=country_markup,
                     parse_mode="Markdown")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("choise_category"))
def category_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    result = call.data.split(":")[1]
    users[call.message.from_user.id]['category_var'] = result
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы очень помогли, я теперь понял принцип работы call_data и клавиатур. К сожалению при попытке нажать в настройках на язык, вылезает ошибка: KeyError: 2132508579. А при попытке нажать на "Смотреть новости", выдает ошибку: dict.get() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Обновил ответ, ошибка должна исчезнуть